Can a my husband add a short stay hotel as accommodation for a visiting visa until I get permanent accommodation?
I am a British citizen and my husband is Ethiopian. I just recently moved to the UK for permanent residency but I don’t have my personal house yet. I am currently 6 months pregnant and me and my husband were planning to have the baby here. Because of the short time frame we decided to apply for a visiting visa so he could be here for the due date. I am currently on a waiting list so I don’t have a house to be his accommodation sponsor like I have mentioned earlier we’re overcrowded ourself. What would you suggest? And can we add short stay hotel where he can stay until I sort the house situation?

What is your plan after the birth? Will your husband go back to Ethiopia? Does he have a job there and will he keep it? Will you keep a home there? If not, those are more likely to be issues for a visitor visa. Remember that for this type of visa, he has to convince them that he will go back to Ethiopia (or elsewhere, as long as he leaves the UK) and has a life there (so-called "ties to the home country").

@jacaron brings up the subject of ties to the home country. In this case, the circumstances of a wife and child-to-be are already in the UK will be seen as strongly suggestive that he will remain in the UK after a visit to the UK. We don't know his ties to Ethiopia, but he must be prepared to explain his ties to the home country and show why he'll leave the UK on time. You and he might search "home ties" in the Search Box at the top of this page to see the many other questions and answers here that have addressed this issue.

He’s planning to go back.

But plans can be changed. He needs to convince the authorities that he will not change those plans and indeed will go back. Having plans to move to the UK when  you find a house (that's how I understand your plans at least) might make that quite hard.

Just because he says he'll go back doesn't mean that UK Immigration will believe he'll go back. Without more evidence of his ties to the home country (e.g., minor children there, elderly parents he supports and cares for, significant employment there to which he must return, etc.) he may well be refused either for a visitor visa or later at the UK port of entry.

He has a job back in Et. Okay say he passes with the accommodation being a hotel. Can  he stay by me after he gets to the UK?

But jobs can be left (without warning, or maybe he can have made some arrangement with his boss) and UK authorities know (and have probably seen) that, so while a job in his home country do count in his favour (for getting a tourist visa) it doesn't make it guaranteed. And if he intends to leave the job within a year (or however long it takes you to find a house) that does not signal it to be a job he absolutely will go back to.

Okay so what do you suggest would be a good reason

Begin by reviewing this Travel.SE question and answer.

What kind of accommodation are you living in? If it’s privately rented or local authority accommodation, you very likely need permission from the landlord/accommodation provider for your husband to stay with you.

Provided you can afford it, there is no problem with that. In fact, it will probably improve his chances (marginally). Having his wife and newborn child living in the UK is already a strong reason for your husband to want to stay in the UK rather than return to Ethiopia. If you had a house to live in as a family it would be even more tempting.
